# tmux window_name(#W) shows long path in windows-status-format

Tags: tmux, centos7

I'm using CentOS 7, and Tmux 2.0. I found the windows-status-format shows $PS1:
[image: tmux]

I checked the [tmux manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS), it shows:

> window_name            #W       Name of window

I don't understand why it works in RHEL6.6 (in RHEL6.6, tmux 1.6, the tab name shows "bash"), but it shows path in CentOS 7.
And How can I restore the same format?

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
$ uname -a
Linux marslojiao.engma.symantec.com 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My tmux configuration: https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/blob/master/Configs/HOME/Tmux/.tmux.conf

Thanks in advanced.

-----------First Update------------
My PS1 as blow:

```
echo "$PS1" | cat -v
\n\[\033[30;1m\]M-bM-^TM-^LM-bM-^TM-^@ (\u@\h \[\033[31;1m\]\w\[\033[30;1m\]) ->\nM-bM-^TM-^TM-bM-^TM-^@ `if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[1\;30m\]\$\[\e[1m\]; else echo \[\e[1\;31m\]\$\[\e[0m\]; fi` \[\033[0m\]
```

This is the PS1 configuration:

```
# ┌─ (USERNAME@HOSTNAME PATH) ->
# └─ $
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]
then
  export PS1="\n\[\033[30;1m\]┌─ (\u@\h \[\033[31;1m\]\w\[\033[30;1m\]) ->\n└─ \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[1\;30m\]\\$\[\e[1m\]; else echo \[\e[1\;31m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \[\033[0m\]"
  export PS2="\[\033[30;1m\] ->\[\033[30;1m\] \[\033[0m\]"
else
  export PS1="\n\[\033[30;1m\]\[\033(0\]l\[\033(B\]\[\033(0\]q\[\033(B\] (\u@\h \[\033[31;1m\]\w\[\033[30;1m\]) ->\n\[\033(0\]m\[\033(B\]\[\033(0\]q\[\033(B\] \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\
e[1\;30m\]\\$\[\e[1m\]; else echo \[\e[1\;31m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \[\033[0m\]"
  export PS2="\[\033[30;1m\] ->\[\033(0\]q\[\033(B\] \[\033[0m\]"
fi
```

Actually, I've disabled the all of my settings to debug the issue. But nothing different.

Comment: There may be something in your bash configuration. What is PS1? Please include the output of `echo "$PS1" | cat -v`

Comment: Hi @Random832, I've updated my question for $PS1. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asked [github:tmux/tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/260#issuecomment-168951711), set [allow-rename to off](https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/blob/b4bfff8483c4a7a6c75b1f040ba66cbd4b321548/Configs/HOME/Tmux/.tmux.conf#L20) will prevent show long-long-path in *windows-status-format*:

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```